# STM32CUBEPGROGRAMMER: You are using OpenJDK, please Install OpenJFX error

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

`STM32CubeProgrammer` seems to be installed yet when I try to run the program I come across with this error.

I have OpenJDK, OpenJFX and Oracle installed on my computer.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Did you check OpenJFX installed folder? I think probably STM32CubeProgrammer can not find the folder.

Comment: yes, the folder contains OpenJFX

Answer (score 2):

If you are using macOS please see my installation guide [here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BmnqrBSQQ/how-to-run-stm32cubeprogrammer-on-macos-catalina-10151-19b88) (tested with macOS Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88).

1.To be sure you use the right java version deinstall all java versions first

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin  
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane  
sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java/ 
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

2.Restart your Mac

3.Check if the deinstallation was successful

```
~ java -version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

4.Now install " [jdk-8u231-macosx-x64](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) "

5.Check your java version after installation

```
~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

6.Go to the directory where the STM32CubeProgrammer installer is located. For example

```
~ cd /Users/myName/Desktop/en
```

7.Install [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html)

```
en sudo java -jar SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.2.1.exe
6. The result should be
Command line arguments: 
====================
Installation started
Framework: 1.6.0_65-b14-468 (Apple Inc.)
Platform: mac_osx,version=10.15.1,arch=x86,symbolicName=null,javaVersion=1.8.0_231
Installation finished
```

8.Now you can start STM32CubeProgrammer

Comment: I follow instructions to install STM32CubeProgrammer on macOS 10.15.5, it went well, but once installed, if I try to launch the app from the application folder, nothing happens... any idea ?

Comment: Was the deinstallation of java successful? I had the same experience with the wrong version.

Comment: my bad, I did not completely uninstall java. Now it works, thanks !

Comment: This process does NOT work for me with Catalina 10.15.6, Java JDK 1.8.0_261, and STMCubeProgrammer version 2.5.0. The install seems to go fine, but when you try to open the app, no window appears, and the app seems to quit

Comment: EDIT: I got it to work with an extra step. You need to manually move the jre into the app folder. The install process looks for it in a very strange place and then fails. See https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BmnqrB/how-to-run-stm32cubeprogrammer-on-macos-catalina-10151-19b88?t=1614640967463

Answer (score 0):

I was a little confused too until I noticed that the instructions above instruct you to download a past version of STMCubeProgrammer -> VERSION 2.2

When visiting the download page from the link emailed to you, note that there is a Version: selection box. Open it and choose 2.2 then click the download button. Resume the instructions above and you should be good to go.

Good luck!